# What's the original cardboard cartridge inlay for Pokemon Red/Blue?

Tags: pokemon-series

Does anyone know what the original cardboard cartridge holder is in boxed version of Pokemon Red/Blue? (I would like to know about the European version.)
I know there are two types:

**Cartridge gap on the top/bottom centered:**
[image]

**Cartridge gap in the middle centered:**
[image]

Which of these is the original?

Answer (score 1):

I live in Italy and I own an English version of Pokemon Blue, but it doesn't have none of those designs. (I'm starting to think I own an American copy.)

This is a photo of the cardboard cartridge holder:

[image]

And this is the actual position of the cartridge in respect to the box:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that seems like an American copy to me. On the cartridge it says USA-1 on the left side. Also the E for Everyone is only on american boxes.

Comment: @LuukLG Seems plausible. Also the "blue version" font is different. Anyway, if it can help you, my Italian Pokemon Yellow has the middle centered inlay layout.

Comment: I had the german one, the original had it to side of the walls. The second edition/following editions had it centered.